# Respoke api authentication error

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, video

I am implementing iOS app where I have to implement Respoke SDK for audio and video calling. Audio and video functionality is working fine in development mode but In production mode it gives me error "Api authentication error". I have used this code for production:

```
        [self.client connectWithTokenID:[[aryResult valueForKey:@"data"]valueForKey:@"token"] initialPresence:nil errorHandler:^(NSString *errorMessage)
         {
             [self showError:errorMessage];
         }];
```

For reference, I have used this : [Respoke Documentation](https://docs.respoke.io/client/ios/guide/authentication.html)

Please tell me what is missing in my end. Please help me out.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the issue by adding some lines of code. Now for the production mode, code will be this:

```
if (!sharedRespokeClient)
{
    // Create a Respoke client instance to be used for the duration of the application
    sharedRespokeClient = [[Respoke sharedInstance] createClient];
}

sharedRespokeClient.delegate = self;
[sharedRespokeClient connectWithTokenID:tokenStringFromServer initialPresence:nil errorHandler:^(NSString *errorMessage) {
            [self showError:errorMessage];
        }];
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems most likely you are having one of these problems:

1. The value returned by `[[aryResult
   valueForKey:@"data"]valueForKey:@"token"]` is not exactly the same
   as the value returned by the Respoke server when asking for a
   brokered authentication token from
   `https://api.respoke.io/v1/tokens` due to URL encoding of the data
   between the server and your iOS application or something similar.
2. The brokered authentication token is only valid for 20 seconds, so
   perhaps too much time has passed before your iOS application
   attempts to use it.
3. You have not switched your application out of
   development mode on the Respoke developer portal, or have not
   created a role to use when authenticating. [This documentation
   page](https://docs.respoke.io/client/ios/guide/authentication.html)
   explains how to properly set up your application and define a role
   for using brokered authentication. You can also use the example code
   on that page to make sure that you are getting a valid token for
   your application. This would help make sure you have your account
   configured correctly.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But I have resolved the issue by adding this code:
  if (!sharedRespokeClient)
        {
            // Create a Respoke client instance to be used for the duration of the application
            sharedRespokeClient = [[Respoke sharedInstance] createClient];
        }

        sharedRespokeClient.delegate = self;